# DynamoDBLocal : How can I start and stop DB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I have a "dynamodb_helper.js" and I use the [local-dynamo](https://github.com/Medium/local-dynamo) to emulate DynamoDB locally.
I'm able to start the server and run it successfully before my test, but the stopDB() does not seem to work. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated. So the server child-process still keeps running even after the test ends.

Please find my code below.

```
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var localDynamo = require('local-dynamo');
var dynamoServer = null;
var dynamodb = null;
var dynamo = null;

module.exports = {
  startDB: function() {
    dynamoServer = localDynamo.launch({
     port: 4567,
     detached: true,
     heap: '512m',
     stdio: 'pipe'
    })
    var awsConfig = require('../lib/util').ymlParser('aws');
    AWS.config.update(awsConfig);
    AWS.config.update({
     accessKeyId: "TestData",
     secretAccessKey: "TestData",
     region: "localhost",
     endpoint: "http://localhost:4567"
    });
    dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    dynamo = dynamodb.DocumentClient;
  },

  stopDB: function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        dynamoServer.kill();
      }, 1000)
  },

  createTable: function() {
    var params = {
        TableName : "Movies",
        KeySchema: [
            { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
            { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions: [
            { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
            { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
            ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 10
        }
    };
    dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add at the top:-**

```
var treeKill = require('tree-kill');
```

**Change the stopDB as mentioned below:-**

```
stopDB : function() {
    console.log("Stop the dynamodb");
    console.log("Dynamodb pid number :" + dynamoServer.pid);        

    treeKill(dynamoServer.pid, 'SIGTERM', function(err) {
        if (err === null) {
            console.log("Dynamodb process has been killed");    
        } else {
            console.log("Dynamodb process hasn't been killed : " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }

    });
},
```

Use treeKill to kill the process as "kill" method doesn't really kill the process.

> Note that while the function is called kill, the signal delivered to
>   the child process may not actually terminate the process.

[Child Process Kill Reference Document](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal)

Comment: I am just wondering whether my answer helped to resolve the issue? If yes, May I request you to accept the answer?

Comment: Hi .... Thanks for helping out on this. I'm yet to try this out. Will check and confirm it.

Comment: HI .. the given solution is working as expected. - the dynamodb process gets killed. Just that it says, "Dynamodb process hasn't been killed : undefined". Tried printing "err" and it shows undefined.  Not sure why the "else" block is executed, but still the solution works. Thanks!